# numpy.heaviside and machine precision

Tags: python, numpy

I have some problems with the [numpy.heaviside](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.heaviside.html) function. Essentially it gives different results when I seemingly pass the same values into the function.

According to the documentation it gives

```
                      0   if x1 < 0
heaviside(x1, x2) =  x2   if x1 == 0
                      1   if x1 > 0
```

I believe that the trouble is the `x1==0` comparison. There are in principle two options for this:

1. Check if the value is zero to within machine precision.
2. Check if the value is actually zero.

I assumed that numpy would do 1., but now I think that it does 2.

Is there any way to circumvent this problem?

Comment: *"Essentially it gives different results when I seemingly pass the same values into the function."*  It would be easier to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Without that, it is not clear what the problem is.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser apologies, I forgot. I found the answer myself in the meantime, and I have given a minimal working example there.

Comment: @samcarter that works super well! thanks a lot! Also thanks for the upvotes and going through the effort of posting the answer as a comment here ;-) Do you mind if I take your code and post it (with reference to you of course) under my question on TeX SE? Some other people seemed interested. Also: what happened to your TeX SE account??

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. The problem seems to be indeed that numpy.heaviside uses an [np.equal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html)-like zero check. Here is a function that uses [np.isclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.3/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) instead.

```
import numpy as np
def heaviside_close(x1, x2):
    closeCheck = np.isclose(x1, np.zeros_like(x1))
    heavisideBare = np.heaviside(x1, 0.0)
    zeroVal = np.where(closeCheck, x2, 0.0)-np.where(closeCheck, heavisideBare, np.zeros_like(heavisideBare))
    result = heavisideBare+zeroVal
    return result
print(heaviside_close(np.asarray([-1., -0.1, 1e-20, 0.1, 1.]), 0.5))
# >>> [0.  0.  0.5 1.  1. ]
print(np.heaviside(np.asarray([-1., -0.1, 1e-20, 0.1, 1.]), 0.5))
# >>> [0.  0.  1.  1.  1. ]
```